# "Error: Command failed with exit code 1: npm install" when create a gatsby site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm a newbie in gatsby, everytime I try to create a gatsby site I am getting this error:

> Error: Command failed with exit code 1: npm install

I tried this :

```
$ gatsby new gatsby-simplefolio https://github.com/cobidev/gatsby-simplefolio
```

I'm using Windows 10, node -v14.14.0, npm -v6.14.8, Gatsby CLI version: 2.12.109

**Result:**

```
$ gatsby new gatsby-simplefolio-2 https://github.com/cobidev/gatsby-simplefolio
info Creating new site from git: https://github.com/cobidev/gatsby-simplefolio.git
Cloning into 'gatsby-simplefolio-2'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 70, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (70/70), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (58/58), done.
remote: Total 70 (delta 3), reused 48 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (70/70), 7.24 MiB | 528.00 KiB/s, done.
?[32msuccess?[39m Created starter directory layout
?[34minfo?[39m Installing packages...
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: joi is leaving the @hapi organization and moving back to 'joi' (https://github.com/sideway/joi/issues/2411)
npm WARN deprecated eslint-loader@2.2.1: This loader has been deprecated. Please use eslint-webpack-plugin
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/formula@2.0.0: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version
of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated

> bufferutil@4.0.1 install C:\Users\Abhik\Documents\Gatsby Practice & Projects\gatsby-simplefolio-2\node_modules\bufferutil
> node-gyp-build

'Projects\gatsby-simplefolio-2\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Abhik\Documents\node-gyp-build\bin.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\babel-plugin-add-module-exports\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0: wanted: {"node":"<8.10.0"}
(current: {"node":"14.14.0","npm":"6.14.8"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0
npm WARN bootstrap@4.5.3 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must
install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.5.3 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.16.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.34.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/parser@2.34.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@5.2.1 requires a peer of eslint@6.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@5.2.1 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-react-hooks@1.x || 2.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-loader@2.2.1 requires a peer of eslint@>=1.6.0 <7.0.0 but none is installed.
You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN acorn-dynamic-import@4.0.0 requires a peer of acorn@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN theme-ui@0.2.52 requires a peer of @mdx-js/react@^1.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bufferutil@4.0.1 install: `node-gyp-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bufferutil@4.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Abhik\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-19T12_48_11_989Z-debug.log

 ERROR 

Command failed with exit code 1: npm install



  Error: Command failed with exit code 1: npm install

  - error.js:56 makeError
    [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/[execa]/lib/error.js:56:11

  - index.js:114 handlePromise
    [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/[execa]/index.js:114:26

  - task_queues.js:93 processTicksAndRejections
    internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5

  - init-starter.js:142 install
    [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/lib/init-starter.js:142:7

  - init-starter.js:209 clone
    [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/lib/init-starter.js:209:3

  - init-starter.js:350 initStarter
    [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/lib/init-starter.js:350:5

  - create-cli.js:430
    [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/lib/create-cli.js:430:7
```